# Error when compiling android dependency flavor

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-flavors

I'm making an application that has ads and the same without ads. I created two flavors like this:

```
productFlavors {
    noAds {
        applicationId 'com.example.pro'
    }
    ads { }
}
```

and declared dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.0.1'
    adsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
}
```

The app will compile with `compile` instead of `adsCompile` but I don't want to include something that is not needed.

I can compile the ads flavor without an error, but noAds throws this errors:

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class AdView
error: cannot find symbol class AdRequest
```

This errors appears in the ads flavor class (com.example.Main), but not in the noAds class.

Also, if I substitute `adsCompile` with `compile` and generate the noAds APK, the app will have two icons in the applications launcher. One of them will works and the other doesn't.

Comment: This happens because you have general code for the `AdMob` dependency no matter the flavor, but you add the dependency only for the `ads` flavor.
I suggest you put your Ads code into an helper class which does something only on the `ads` flavor.